# FLOT plot chart legend CSS being overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am experimenting with the FLOT plot tool and having some problem with the legend.  Specifically, the CSS for the legend must be being overwritten somewhere in my code because the legend is looking like this:

[image: bad legend formatting]

When I try to pass legend options to the plot, they do not appear. What do I need to do fix this CSS problem?  Thanks.

Here is some of the code I am working with:

```
                    var options = {
                    series: {
                        lines: { show: true },
                        points: { show: true },
                    legend: {
                        margin: 5
                    }

                    }
                };

                $.plot("#flotcontainer", [ json ], options);
```

Comment: You asked a question about fixing CSS, but you didn't share your CSS with us...

Comment: @Daniel make a fiddle for your problem

Comment: My apologies for this poor question.  It was late at night, and I posted this question about CSS, without providing any of the CSS.  My bad.  Anyway, seeing your comments made me realize the error in my ways.  My problem was that the default table style of my theme was causing the legend table in FLOT to have `width="100%"`.  Once I commented-out that particular style in my theme, the legend in FLOT was formatting correctly.  Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

The `margin` option from `flot` specifies the distance to the plot edge which seems about right at 5 pixels. Try to set the `position` option too (see the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-legend) for more information).